# Open all selected PDFs in one Preview window - macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, preview, high-sierra

As of High Sierra, Preview always opens all selected PDFs in single windows for each document. In the preferences menu, there is an option to change this behaviour for images, but not PDFs.

This is a real bummer and makes Preview a lot less useful. What is Apple thinking?

Ok, the real question is: How do we fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301775/preview-cant-open-multiple-pdf-in-same-window?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can install Preview 9.0 again from https://github.com/frhd/macOS-Preview9.0.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the default behavior, you can open new files in tabs instead of new windows by modifying a system preference.

Go to **System Preferences** > **Dock**, and in the middle of the window change:

**Prefer tabs when opening documents:** *from* **In Full Screen Only** *to* **Always**

Comment: It does on my machine. i did validate it. i'm running high Sierra with latest Preview.

Comment: i now have 2 open PDF files in one window but with separate tabs.

Comment: If you gave me the downvote I'd appreciate you removing it. This is a solution and the one I use.

Comment: This is no solution. And it does not work. Opening all files in separate tabs yields nothing. You cannot batch process them

Comment: Sorry, but it worked for me and others.  I went thru this last year when I posted this answer.  The person who downvoted the answer then found out it did work and withdrew his downvote. Maybe checking things on your end before rudely saying that answer is wrong. Maybe things have changed since November 2017. I don't know.

Comment: Maybe checking thing on my end? What do you think made me write this comment? Right, it did NOT work on my end.